# Using combo box to select what paths and registry keys to use

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

**Purpose:**

With Inno Setup I want to create an installer with a dropdown list in the install wizard.

The choice made in the wizards defines 2 variables:
One for the folder location and the other for the location in the registry.

**Problem:**

Variables are defined as global in `[Code]`, but are not used in `[Files]` and `[Registry]`

**Code:**

The two variables are: `strData1` & `strData2`

I was trying to retrieve them with functions: `strData1returner` & `strData2returner`

```pascal
[Setup]
...

[Dirs]    
Name: "C:\Program Files\CompanyName\{code:strData1returner}"

[Files]
Source: "C:\SomeDll.dll"; \
  DestDir: "C:\Program Files\CompanyName\{code:strData1returner}\"; Flags: ignoreversion;

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; subkey: "{code:strData2returner}"; flags: createvalueifdoesntexist

[Code]
var
  Button: TNewButton;
  ComboBox: TNewComboBox;
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;     
  strData1: string;
  strData2: string;

procedure ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case ComboBox.ItemIndex of
    0:
    begin
      strData1 := 'Subfolder';
      strData2 := 'SOFTWARE\CompanyName';
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  DescLabel: TLabel;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectDir, 'Caption', 'Description');

  DescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  DescLabel.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  DescLabel.Left := 0;
  DescLabel.Top := 0;
  DescLabel.Caption := 'Select an item...';

  ComboBox := TNewComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
  ComboBox.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  ComboBox.Left := 0;
  ComboBox.Top := DescLabel.Top + DescLabel.Height + 6;  
  ComboBox.Width := 220;
  ComboBox.Style := csDropDownList;
  ComboBox.Items.Add('Choice1');
  ComboBox.ItemIndex := 0;
  ComboBox.OnChange := @ComboBoxChange;
end;

function strData1returner(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result :=  strData1;
end;

function strData2returner(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result :=  strData2;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was only a single option: "Choice1" - So I added a second (Choice2), and alternative values for that second option, under index 1.

You should also initialize the two variables in InitializeWizard, in case the user doesn't change the combobox value. The ComboBoxChange procedure is only executed when the value actually changes, not when the default is accepted via no action.

Also, in trying to reproduce your problem I noticed a syntax problem causing compilation errors with createvalueifdoesntexistcreatevalueifdoesntexist - naturally, you just need one of those.

```
[Dirs]    
Name: "C:\Program Files\CompanyName\{code:strData1returner}"

[Files]
Source: "C:\SomeDll.dll"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files\CompanyName\{code:strData1returner}\"; Flags: ignoreversion;

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; subkey:"{code:strData2returner}"; flags: createvalueifdoesntexist

[Code]
var
  Button: TNewButton;
  ComboBox: TNewComboBox;
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;     
  strData1: string;
  strData2: string;

procedure ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case ComboBox.ItemIndex of
    0:
    begin
      strData1 := 'Subfolder';
      strData2 := 'SOFTWARE\CompanyName';
    end;
    1:
    begin
      strData1 := 'Subfolder2';
      strData2 := 'SOFTWARE\CompanyName2';
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  DescLabel: TLabel;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectDir, 'Caption', 'Description');

  DescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  DescLabel.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  DescLabel.Left := 0;
  DescLabel.Top := 0;
  DescLabel.Caption := 'Select an item...';

  ComboBox := TNewComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
  ComboBox.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  ComboBox.Left := 0;
  ComboBox.Top := DescLabel.Top + DescLabel.Height + 6;  
  ComboBox.Width := 220;
  ComboBox.Style := csDropDownList;
  ComboBox.Items.Add('Choice1');
  ComboBox.Items.Add('Choice2');
  ComboBox.ItemIndex := 0;
  ComboBox.OnChange := @ComboBoxChange;
  strData1 := 'Subfolder';
  strData2 := 'SOFTWARE\CompanyName';
end;

function strData1returner(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result :=  strData1;
end;

function strData2returner(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result :=  strData2;
end;
```

The code above is working as I think you expect it to here.

Comment: damnit it was so obvious, forgot to initialize, thanks for the help! [my first attempt at inno setup]

Answer (score 0):

Actually your attempt to use global variables just complicates the code.

Access the `ComboBox.ItemIndex` directly from [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) implementations like:

```pascal
[Dirs]    
Name: "{app}\{code:GetSelectedSubfolder}"

[Files]
Source: "C:\SomeDll.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\{code:GetSelectedSubfolder}"

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "{code:GetSelectedSubkey}"

[Code]

var
  ComboBox: TNewComboBox;

procedure InitializeWizard;
{ ... }
begin
  { ... }
  ComboBox := TNewComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
  { ... }
  ComboBox.Items.Add('Choice1');
  ComboBox.Items.Add('Choice2');
  ComboBox.ItemIndex := 0;
end;

function GetSelectedSubfolder(Param: String): String;
begin
  case ComboBox.ItemIndex of
    0: Result := 'Subfolder1';
    1: Result := 'Subfolder2';
  end;
end;

function GetSelectedSubkey(Param: String): String;
begin
  case ComboBox.ItemIndex of
    0: Result := 'SOFTWARE\CompanyName1';
    1: Result := 'SOFTWARE\CompanyName2';
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create global variables like this:

```
#define CustomVarName "Value"
```

More specific information about here: [#define](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define)

Comment: How does this answer the question? And it's not a global variable anyway, it's a preprocessor variable.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Good sir, I am but a beginner, my understanding of global variables was limited in definition, using this (being correct by convention or not) helped me. I thought I aught to give back my "findings" for any other beginner that might be struggling.

Comment: I do not even remotely understand, how does a preprocessor variable relate to this question?

Comment: This helps to use a variable in all sections, question might have been better stated, my apoligies.

Comment: You cannot use preprocessor variable to manage run time objects like a combo box.

Comment: If you have a different problem that can be solved using preprocessor variable, go ahead and post a new question (and answer it, you have a solution already).